# SQL select from two tables with exclude

Tags: sql

TABLE A

```
id, name
```

TABLE B

```
id, A.id
```

I need to select all rows from TABLE A where id does not exist in table B (column A.id)

Answer (score 0):

The query is almost exactly as you describe it:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.aid = a.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe like this:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A
WHERE A.ID NOT IN (SELECT B.A_ID FROM B);
```

And here is the demo:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=847e28b03e9c4c1724ff13fc41117bdd